# Qiuerying for XML bloxks with tags when using javax.xml.xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to fetch an XML block (not just element values) using an xpath. Ran into a couple of articles like this, http://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-tutorial-with-examples, and am able to get good responses for the queries mentioned. However, how do I get an XML block as a response for an xpath like **/Employees** ?

i.e., Get a response,

```
<Employee id="1">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="2">
    <age>35</age>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="3">
    <age>40</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="4">
    <age>25</age>
    <name>Meghna</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
```

and not,

```
    29
    Pankaj
    Male
    Java Developer


    35
    Lisa
    Female
    CEO


    40
    Tom
    Male
    Manager


    25
    Meghna
    Female
    Manager
```

Code:

```
package com.eugthom.xmlBlock;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XpathEvaluate {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse("C:\\Users\\thoeu01\\Desktop\\a.xml");

        // Create XPathFactory object
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        // Create XPath object
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        String nodeName = getEntireNode(doc, xpath);
        System.out.println("Node is: " + nodeName);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String getEntireNode(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Employees");
//          name = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
        name = expr.evaluate(doc);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you currently have which is not working for you?

Comment: @ug_ it's basically the same as mentioned in the link, with small tweaks. Added the code to the question.

Comment: You need to serialize the returned DOM nodes to XML markup, with Java you can use DOM Level 3 Load and Save or the JAXP default Transformer.